# Magento 2 - Short Description is not showing!

Tags: magento2, product

Short description is not showing for some reason, I have declared the block again in a new container after price block, yet not showing!

```
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.description" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.overview" remove="true"/>

    <referenceBlock name="content">
        <container name="product.content.overview" htmlClass="overview" htmlTag="div" after="product.info.price">
            <block as="shortdescription" class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" group="detailed_info" name="product.content.shortdescription" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getShortDescription</argument>
                    <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">short_description</argument>
                    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">overview</argument>
                    <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
                    <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Overview</argument>
                    <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop=&quot;description&quot;</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </container>

        <container name="product.content.essentials" htmlClass="essentials" htmlTag="div" after="product.info.media">
            <block as="description" class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" group="detailed_info" name="product.content.description" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getDescription</argument>
                    <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">description</argument>
                    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">description</argument>
                    <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
                    <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Details</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </container>
    </referenceBlock>

    <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" group="detailed_info" name="product.info.deliveryandreturns" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/deliveryandreturns.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Delivery &amp; Returns</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" group="detailed_info" name="product.info.sizechart" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getSizechart</argument>
                <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">sizechart</argument>
                <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">sizechart</argument>
                <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
                <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop=&quot;sizechart&quot;</argument>
                <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Size Chart</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>

    <move element="product.info.details" as="product-tabs" destination="product.content.essentials" after="product.content.description"/>

</body>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why titles for Description and Short Description not showing on Product Page?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/310672/why-titles-for-description-and-short-description-not-showing-on-product-page)

Answer (score 0):

Without removing the "**product.info.overview**" block and re-declared again, You can move short description after price this way.

*Try this -*

> < move element="product.info.overview" destination="product.info.main" before="product.info"/>

OR

> < move element="product.info.overview" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.price"/>

OR

> < move element="product.info.price" destination="product.info.main" before="product.info.overview"/>

Comment: It did not work, it is not showing in the product page as a whole.